# Angular.js required and ng-required not working for <textarea></textarea>

Tags: angularjs

I can not get Angular.js `required` or `ng-required` to work. I want it to where if the user hits ok, they have to have some text in the textbox.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>Your change will be logged. Please provide a ticket number or comment for reference</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" 
                ng-model="commentBox.text" 
                ng-required="commentBox.text">
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Scratching my head.....

Comment: If you want to make the textarea required then just do `<textarea ... required>` . `ng-required` just adds the attribute to the test area based on a boolean value.. i.e `ng-required="true"`

Comment: I tried just `required` and still would not work. I was able to hit submit ok without any text entered.

Comment: No, but I also tried to embed the <textarea> instead of <form> but still did not have success.

Comment: Here is an example http://plnkr.co/edit/vT3SuIEO9SCaUzdkOgId?p=preview

Answer (score 14, accepted):

two things:

1. make sure that value you are passing to ng-required is boolean (to be technically correct, it should evaluate to boolean)

   ```
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" 
       ng-model="commentBox.text" 
       ng-required="commentBox.textRequired">
   </textarea>

   //somewhere in your controller
   $scope.commentBox.textRequired = true
   ```
2. you would need form.$invalid on your button

   ```
   <button type="submit" ng-disabled="formname.$invalid" ng-click="onsubmit()"></button>
   ```

so to complete it

```
   <ng-form name="exampleForm">
     <textarea type="text" ng-model="commentBox.text" ng-required="true"></textarea>
     <button ng-disabled="exampleForm.$invalid" ng-click="onsubmit()"></button>
   </ng-form>
```

Comment: `ng-required` doesn't need to be a boolean. It just has to evaluate to `true` in order to add the `required` property.

Also, disabling the submit button will not prevent any submit handlers registered using `ng-submit`.

Answer (score 2):

also without adding another prop, you could set it to
    ng-required="!!commentBox.text"